# Find out the laplace tranform of given equation and also plot the poles and zeros on it.

Tags: laplace-transform, laplace-method

Equation is:

L{${(t+1)}^2e^t$}

By using the properties of Laplace, I got this result
$$\frac{-2}{(s-1)^3} +\frac{2}{(s-1)^2} + \frac{1}{(s-1)}$$
How do I plot the zeros and poles? Also, what does it mean to plot on s plane, How is it different from the normal plane.

Comment: No, The question is from textbook.

Answer (score 1):

$s$ plane is nothing but complex plane where you plot poles and zeros. Zeros are the values where $L(s)=0$ and Poles are the values where $L(s)\mapsto \infty$

Upon simplifying 
$$\frac{-2}{(s-1)^3} +\frac{2}{(s-1)^2} + \frac{1}{(s-1)}=\frac{s^2-3}{\left(s-1\right)^3}$$

So the pole is $-1$
And zeros are $\pm \sqrt{3}$

While plotting you denote poles with $\times$ and zeros with $O$
So there will be a $x$ on imaginary axis at $-1$ and two $O$ at $\pm \sqrt{3}$ on real axis.

Comment: Where can I find good tutorials on this topic.

Comment: I studied from Thoma' calculus.